# Cannot resolve dependency with within imported node module called "node-fetch"

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, parcel, npm-package

Still somewhat of a beginner in Node, so apologies for what might be a newbie question. I have a small Chrome extension that I built where the only imported node module is one called `node-fetch`. I've never had trouble running `yarn build` to build a package that includes all the requisite dependencies.  However, when I try to build my current package, yarn throws this error in the console:

```
  /Users/me/Documents/GitHub/my-project/node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js:9:17: Cannot resolve dependency 'node:http'
   7 |  */
   8 |
>  9 | import http from 'node:http';
     |                 ^
  10 | import https from 'node:https';
  11 | import zlib from 'node:zlib';
  12 | import Stream, {PassThrough, pipeline as pump} from 'node:stream';
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
ERROR: "build:bg" exited with 1.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

So, this error is coming from the `node_modules` file myself rather than the code I wrote. Inside the `package.json`, I only declare this one dependency:

```
"dependencies": {
    "node-fetch": "^3.3.0"
  }
```

I tried manually installing the referenced packages and referencing them in the dependencies but to no avail.

What am I missing?

Tried to `yarn build` a package with a dependency on the `node-fetch` module that I import into my code. `yarn` throwing an error on the `node-fetch` module itself when I attempt to build.

Answer (score 0):

Reverting to `^2.6.1` resolves the problem.  Still interested to learn a better solve.